# Cannot find out the testing cases where my code gets Wrong Answer in this Parentheses Sequence Problem

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, parentheses

[This is a problem on OJ](https://hihocoder.com/contest/hiho250/problem/1).

You are given a sequence `S` of parentheses. You are asked to insert into `S` as few parentheses as possible so that the resulting sequence `T` is well matched.

Can you tell how many different `T` you can get?

Assume `S = ())`, you can get either `(())` or `()()`.

One line contains the sequence `S`.

- For 30% of the data, `1 ≤ |S| ≤ 10`.
- For 60% of the data, `1 ≤ |S| ≤ 200`.
- For 100% of the data, `1 ≤ |S| ≤ 1000`.

Output 2 integers indicating the minimum number of parentheses need to be inserted into `S` and the number of different `T`. The number of different `T` may be very large, so output the answer modulo `10^9+7`.

A way to solve this problem is to split the original sequence into two parts. One needs inserting `(` only and the other needs only `)`. This tow parts can be solved in the same way.

Consider a sequence `(()(()`. To get rid of repeating we only insert `)` in front of `(` or at the last position of the sequence. The number of `)` can be inserted at each position is limited, let it be `limit[i]`.

Assume `f[i][j]` as the number of results if `j`; `)` are inserted at the first `i` position, then `f[i][j] = f[i-1][0] + f[i-1][1] + ... f[i-1][min(j, limit[i-1])]`.

However, when I submitted my code, I got 60/100 WA. And I could not test out the cases leading to my Wrong Answer so I don't know how to improve the code.

Attached below is the code that I submitted:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int modulo = pow(10, 9) + 7;

int split(string);
void inverse(string&);
void getInsLimit(vector<int>&, string, int&);
int getNumOfWays(vector<int>);

int record[1001][1001]; // record nums of ways to insert j parenthesies into the first i position

int main() {

    string input;
    while (getline(cin, input)) {
        int LRpos = split(input); // return the pos after the last ele of L 
        string L = input.substr(0, LRpos), R = input.substr(LRpos, input.size() - LRpos);
        inverse(L);

        int insCnt = 0, wayCnt = 0, tmpL = 0, tmpR = 0;


        vector<int> insLimit;
        getInsLimit(insLimit, L, insCnt);
        tmpL = getNumOfWays(insLimit);


        getInsLimit(insLimit, R, insCnt);
        tmpR = getNumOfWays(insLimit);

        if (tmpL == 0 || tmpR == 0) {
            wayCnt = tmpL + tmpR;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < tmpL; ++i) {
                wayCnt += tmpR;
                if (wayCnt >= modulo) {
                    wayCnt -= modulo;
                }
            }

        }

        cout << insCnt << ' ' << wayCnt << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}

int split(string input) {
    int pos = 0;
    int lcnt = 0;
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        if (input[i] == '(') {
            ++lcnt;
        }else {
            --lcnt;
        }
        if (lcnt < 0) { // less than 0 means it needs '('
            lcnt = 0;
            pos = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

void inverse(string &str) {
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        str[i] = str[i] == '(' ? ')':'(';
    }
}

void getInsLimit(vector<int>& insLimit, string str, int& insCnt) {
    insLimit.clear();

    if (str.empty())
        return;

    int lCnt = 0;
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == '(') {
            ++lCnt;
        }else {
            --lCnt;
        }
        if (lCnt > 0 && (i == str.size() - 1 || str[i + 1] == '(')) {
            insLimit.push_back(lCnt);
        } 
        if (lCnt == 0) { // means that it needn't parenthesies at all
            insLimit.clear();
        }
    }

    insCnt += lCnt;
}

int getNumOfWays(vector<int> insLimit) {

    if (insLimit.empty()) {
        return 0; 
    }

    int maxI = insLimit.size() - 1, maxJ = insLimit[maxI];

    memset(record, 0, 1001 * 1001);

    // Initialize the first line
    for (int j = 0; j <= insLimit[0]; ++j) { // can be equal
        record[0][j] = insLimit[0]; // actually it can only be 1
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= maxI; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= insLimit[i]; ++j) { // after limit, record[i][j] = 0, equals initial value
            if (j == 0)
                record[i][j] = 1;
            else {
                record[i][j] = record[i - 1][j] + record[i][j - 1];
                if (record[i][j] >= modulo)
                    record[i][j] -= modulo;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < maxJ; ++j) {
        record[maxI][j] = 0;
    } // logically should be 0, unnecessary in this problem

    return record[maxI][maxJ];
}
```